# Can I introduce myself and my job position in one sentence?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, sentence-combination

I have a such paragraph:

> My name is Yaroslav Konoplov.
>
> I am a software engineer living in Kyiv, Ukraine (UTC+3).

Basically I want to merge these sentences in one.

> I am Yaroslav Konoplov, a software engineer living in Kyiv, Ukraine (UTC+3).

Is this correct?

Comment: You can put as many things together in a sentence as you want. If you feel like it, you can add where you went to school, whether you are married and / or have children, your favorite colour and sports team to the same sentence without any problem. The one thing to keep in mind is that _very_ long sentences are more difficult to understand. Your example is just fine, however.

Comment: It looks all right, but why don't you want to have two sentences?

Comment: @loading... I am writing a profile overview for Upwork and it seems like they limit the number of words.

Comment: Is it important for me to have as few words as possible.

Comment: Your usage is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this construct is perfectly common and acceptable.